# What happens if I use my favicon for apple-touch-icon?

Tags: favicon, icon, ios

I want to stop getting all the `File does not exist: apple-touch-icon...` lines in my error.log but don't want to spend any time at all creating more icon files.

Other than a slightly-blocky icon for anyone who saves my URL to their home screen on an iOS device, are there any downsides to just symlinking each of `apple-touch-icon{-120x120,76x76,}{-precomposed,}.png` to my 20x21 `favicon.ico`?

Comment: I don't have a recommendation. Sorry. I simply cannot remember which one I used, but I did use an online favicon that produced the apple touch icon for me easy-peasy.

Comment: Since `ico` is not `png` it most likely will not work.

Answer (score 4):

[Apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/ConfiguringWebApplications/ConfiguringWebApplications.html) says:

> To specify an icon for the entire website (every page on the website), place an icon file **in PNG format** in the root document folder called apple-touch-icon.png

So file in ICO format definitely won't work.

Comment: @drewbenn I think the result would be the same as if you didn't specify the icon at all.